# Would a statement as a whole count as an expression?

Tags: java, expression

I know an expression makes up a statement, but would the whole statement with the semicolon count as an expression? What if I remove the semicolon, then the statement would not be a statement but just an expression right?

Comment: please show an example of what you are talking about

Comment: Would for example x =5; as a statement also count as an expression?

Comment: @gavinchavez: assignment happens to be an expression, so yes.

Comment: After reading this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html it does not seem like that x = 5; would be an expression. x =5 would be an expression in my understanding if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java language specification [section 14.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) describes "statements".

Some but not all of those "statements" are ["expression statements"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ExpressionStatement).

[Expressions (chapter 15)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html) themselves either appear by themselves in expression statements, or else are constituents of other statements.

To answer the example in your question: in `x = 5;`  there is an expression `x = 5` (specifically an [assignment expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-AssignmentExpression)), but `x = 5;` itself is a statement (specifically an expression statement).

Answer (score 1):

Not all expressions are valid statements, but [some expressions can be used as statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).

For example a pre- or post-increment expression such as `x++` can be used as a statement (which would be `x++`).

But parenthesized expressions (such as `(x)`) are not allowed as statements.

Not all statements are just expressions with a semicolon attached, a trivial counter-example is the empty statement `;` (but also if-statements and many others).

The [relevant section of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) is actually fairly readable.

Comment: So clearly if I said x = 5; x = 5 would be an expression but the whole statement itself of x =5; would not be considered a statement right?